# Stringbuilder with JPA repository

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, repository, stringbuilder

I have a requirement to construct a dynamic service.
I am using Stringbuilder but I am not sure how to use this with JPA repository.

I build an SQL native query using the Stringbuilder.toString() and then pass this to the JPA interface. I get a "syntax error" when I run this.
But when I run the same query which I have build using StringBuilder in DBeaver, I am able to get the results.

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long>

@Query(value = ":strQry", nativeQuery = true)
List<User> findUserDetails(@Param("strQry") String strQry);
```

Comment: I think your proplem not by StringBuilder, you must check syntax of sql query.

Comment: Hi @ThanhLD : I have tried the same query that I build using StringBuilder in DBeaver and it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those things denoted by a leading colon are "bind parameters" you can only replace expressions with bind parameters, i.e. you can use them where you could also use a literal expression like `23` or `'Shrut Biswas'`.

If you want to construct your SQL statement and execute it you'll have to write a [custom method](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.single-repository-behavior), get an `EntityManager` injected and execute something like

```
em.createNativeQuery(yourSqlStatement).getResultList();
```

*Note: Please read up about SQL injection attacks. The combination of concatenating your own SQL statement and not understanding bind parameters is likely to lead to vulnerabilities.*

Comment: Thank you. Yes I have followed the custom method and it works fine !